# TFS build dosn't complete correctly when I use c# 7 feature in my code

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I've installed TFS (version 15.112.26307.0) on windows server 2012 R2. all team members use VS2017 to coding. I've  created an agent (I've tried versions vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.112.0, 2.117.0 ,2.140.0)and set it's MSBuild version  to MSBuild15.0 :

[image]

MSBuild15.0 has already installed on the server :

[image]

But when we use c# 7 features in our code(like "int out x") building code via TFS raise error as below (it use MSBuild14.0 to build our code, why?)

[image]

My agent capabalities is not correct :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Visual Studio Build task. It allows you to specify the Visual Studio version used to run builds.

Comment: if you mean Hosted VS2017 , I dont use it because I dont use azure pipeline. I've created my own agent and set MSBuild15 to build my codes(first pic)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the capabilities cannot be detected by the agent. If you have installed the VS 2017 on the build agent server, then you can try to restart the agent service to check if that works.

If that still not work, you could try below things:

- Add the capabilities manually.

The path of them are（Enterprise version for example):

```
VisualStudio_15.0     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\

VisualStudio_IDE_15.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\

MSBuild_15.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\

MSBuild_15.0_x64  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\

VSTest  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
```

- Specify the path to Msbuild 15.0:

  [image]